# Perl SOAP::Lite WSDL with raw XML

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I want to make a SOAP request with Perl and I want to send raw XML data like

```
$xml = "<IODATA>
  <TEST>
    Hello World
  </TEST>
</IODATA>";
```

I am using SOAP::Lite like this:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service('http://localhost/cms/WebService/RDCMSXMLServer.WSDL');
$soap->Execute($xml, "", "");
```

But when I check the SOAP body my xml is parsed and looks like this:

```
&lt;IODATA&gt;
```

etc.

The WSDL file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<definitions
name='RDCMSXMLServer'
targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/webservice/'
xmlns:wsdlns='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/webservice/'
xmlns:typens='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/type/'
xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
xmlns:stk='http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap-toolkit/wsdl-extension'
xmlns:dime='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/'
xmlns:ref='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/'
xmlns:content='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/content-type/'
xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<types>
    <schema
        targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/type/'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
        xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
        elementFormDefault='qualified'>

        <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'/>
        <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/'/>
        <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/content-type/'/>

    </schema>
</types>

<message name='XmlServer.Execute'>
    <part name='sParamA' type='xsd:string'/>
    <part name='sErrorA' type='xsd:anyType'/>
    <part name='sResultInfoA' type='xsd:anyType'/>
</message>

<message name='XmlServer.ExecuteResponse'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
    <part name='sErrorA' type='xsd:anyType'/>
    <part name='sResultInfoA' type='xsd:anyType'/>
</message>

<portType name='XmlServerSoapPort'>

    <operation name='Execute' parameterOrder='sParamA sErrorA sResultInfoA'>
        <input message='wsdlns:XmlServer.Execute'/>
        <output message='wsdlns:XmlServer.ExecuteResponse'/>
    </operation>

</portType>

<binding name='XmlServerSoapBinding' type='wsdlns:XmlServerSoapPort' >

    <stk:binding preferredEncoding='UTF-8'/>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

    <operation name='Execute'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/action/XmlServer.Execute'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body
                use='encoded'
                namespace='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/message/'
                encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
                parts='sParamA sErrorA sResultInfoA'/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body
                use='encoded'
                namespace='http://tempuri.org/RDCMSXMLServer/message/'
                encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
                parts='Result sErrorA sResultInfoA'/>
        </output>
    </operation>

</binding>

<service name='RDCMSXMLServer' >
    <port name='XmlServerSoapPort' binding='wsdlns:XmlServerSoapBinding' >
        <soap:address location='http://10.1.102.104:80/CMS/webservice/RDCMSXMLServer.WSDL'/>
    </port>
</service>

 </definitions>
```

How can I change that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Chris

Comment: Please show some complete code. Your first example is wrong, the quotes are missing. Please also show your WSDL file, or at least what is expected.

Comment: Hi "simbabaque", I added the WSDL and changed the example correctly.

Comment: I don't quite see why you would send raw XML with a module of which the whole point is to abstract the XML away so you don't need to care about it. Also, the message you are trying to send is not what the service expects. It will return an error.

Comment: How do you get the SOAP body?

Comment: Can you send me how you would request the service?

Comment: I am using SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug'

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make a SOAP request with Perl and I want to send raw XML
> data

Let's see. In the [SOAP::Data doc](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP::Data#COMPOSING-MESSAGES-USING-RAW-XML) there's a part about using raw XML. Here it is:

> In some circumstances you may need to encode a message using raw
> unserialized XML text. To instantiate a SOAP::Data object using raw
> XML, do the following:
>
> ```
> $xml_content = "<foo><bar>123</bar></foo>";
> $elem = SOAP::Data->type('xml' => $xml_content);
> ```

You might be able to do this with your code, too. It might look like this:

```
my $xml = <<'XML';
<IODATA>
  <TEST>
    Hello World
  </TEST>
</IODATA>
XML

my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service('http://localhost/cms/WebService/RDCMSXMLServer.WSDL');
my $res = $soap->sayHello(SOAP::Data->type( 'xml' => $xml ));
```

---

**However**, this will not work as there is no method named `sayHello` defined in your WSDL file! I did not try your WSDL, but you might want to read through the [SOAP::Lite docs](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP::Lite) again to do that yourself.

I believe it could work [like this](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP::Lite#RPC-ENCODED), or similar (untested!):

```
use SOAP::Lite;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service("http://localhost/cms/WebService/RDCMSXMLServer.WSDL");
my $result = $soap->Execute($sParamA, $sErrorA,$ sResultInfoA);
print $result->result();
```

You might also find [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691616) helpful.